# How to Disable Only Cut option From EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-widget

i have two EditText for UserName and Password. first UserName EditText will be Visible.it will check Valid UserName.Then, Password EditText will be visible. i want user to copy the username but don't want to cut.
how to disable the Cut Option.
But below code Disable all the Option.
Code :

```
     @Override
                                public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
                                    return false;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {

                                     return false;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
                                    return false;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {

                                }
                            });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First set a **customSelectionActionModeCallback**.
You could identify the cut option by its id: android.R.id.cut

So your code in the **onCreateActionMode** from the **ActionMode.Callback** would look like this:

```
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(android.R.id.cut); 
    if (menuItem != null) {
        menuItem.setVisible(false);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Or you could even remove it by using **menu.removeItem(android.R.id.cut)**.

Also null-check for menu.findItem(android.R.id.cut) because it might return null when calling setVisible on it.